# What's a good replacement for MenuMeters on the newest macOS?

Tags: software-recommendation, menu-bar

https://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/ says it does not support the newest version of macOS any more.

What's a good replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best replacement for MenuMeters is: [**MenuMeters**](https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan/)!

> It's a port to OS X El Capitan 10.11 and later of our beloved utility MenuMeters by Alex Harper, at http://ragingmenace.com. As he has not yet released the port to OS X 10.11 El Capitan, I made a minimal modification to the source code he has kindly made public so that it runs fine.
>
> Confirmed to run OK on El Capitan 10.11, Sierra 10.12 and High Sierra 10.13.

Take note that currently the above port is somewhat lacking in releasing a new build. To get all the latest updates and features you have to build the binary yourself.

Or: go to another fork at [emcrisostomo/MenuMeters](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/MenuMeters) which includes the latest fixes and has an installer DMG.

Or: go to yet another fork at [axet/MenuMeters](https://gitlab.com/axet/MenuMeters) which adds new features on top.

Answer (score 2):

I switched from MenuMeters to [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) some years ago, and can say it has been an excellent, beautiful and solid piece of software.